# interactive stack which can have checkbox and select the options for stack

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make working model of Stack in which user can select the stack `s1` or `s2` and can perform operations like `push` and `pop`.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stack With Constructor </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Stack </div>
  <div>
    <p id="p1">
      stack
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="stack1" value="s1">s1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="stack2" value="s2">s2
    <br>
    <textarea id="tdisplay"></textarea>
  </div>
  <textarea id="tpush"></textarea>
  <button onclick="doJob()">push</button>
  <button onclick="doJob1()">pop</button>
  <textarea id="tpop"></textarea>

  <script>
    function myfunction() {
      if (document.getElementById("stack1") == true) {
        var s1 = new MyStack();
      }
      if (document.getElementById("stack2") == true) {
        var s2 = new MyStack();

      }
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function push(v) {
      if (this.st === 0) {
        console.log("Stack Overflow");
      } else {
        this.st = this.st - 1;
        this.stk[this.st] = v;
        document.getElementById("tdisplay").value = this.print();;
      }
    }

    function pop() {
      if (this.st === 10) {
        console.log("Stack Underflow");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("tdisplay").innerHTML = "";
        var temp = this.stk[this.st];
        this.st = this.st + 1;

        return temp;
      }
    }

    function print() {
      console.log("Printing Stack");
      return this.stk.reduce((acc, cv, i, arr, ) => {
        console.log(cv);
        return (i) ? acc + " " + "\n" + cv : cv;
      }, '');
    }

    function MyStack() {
      this.st = 10;
      this.stk = new Array(10);
      this.push = push;
      this.pop = pop;
      this.print = print;
    }

    function doJob() {
      var x = document.getElementById("tpush").value;
      s1.push(x);

      document.getElementById("tpush").value = "";
    }

    function doJob1() {
      var y = s1.pop();
      document.getElementById("tpop").value = y;
      document.getElementById("tdisplay").value = s1.print();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm getting problems as follows:

1. I cannot get the output for `pop` value. This means when I press button of pop it should give me the remaining items in the array.
2. I don't know how to use checkbox method. It means when i select `s1` checkbox it should create `s1` stack and I can do operations on it and same as for `s2`.

The result should be proper browser functions for interactive stack so it can work like in following steps:

1. User select `s1` or `s2` stack
2. If he/she selects `s1` then they can work for all operations for `s1`.
3. User can switch between `s2` too and can perform all operations.

I am having issues on the pop function and checkbox working.

Answer (score 1):

This would help you get started in the right direction:

Things I noticed:

1. Incorrect usage of checkbox's boolean value. (use .checked).
2. Also, checkboxes' names were stack1/2 not id(s).

   ```
   <body>
   <div>Stack</div>
   <div>
       <p id="p1">
           stack
       </p>
       <input type="checkbox" id="stack1" value="s1">s1
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="stack2" value="s2">s2
       <br>
       <textarea id="tdisplay"></textarea>
   </div>
   <textarea id="tpush"></textarea>
   <button onclick="doJob()">push</button>
   <button onclick="doJob1()">pop</button>
   <textarea id="tpop"></textarea>

   <script>
       var s1, s2;

       function myfunction() {
           if (document.getElementById("stack1").checked == true) {
               console.log('myFunction called!');
               s1 = new MyStack();
           }
           if (document.getElementById("stack2").checked == true) {
               s2 = new MyStack();
           }
       }


       function push(v) {
           if (this.st === 0) {
               console.log("Stack Overflow");
           } else {
               this.st = this.st - 1;
               this.stk[this.st] = v;
               document.getElementById("tdisplay").value = this.print();
               ;
           }
       }

       function pop() {
           if (this.st === 10) {
               console.log("Stack Underflow");
           } else {
               document.getElementById("tdisplay").innerHTML = "";
               var temp = this.stk[this.st];
               this.st = this.st + 1;

               return temp;
           }
       }

       function print() {
           console.log("Printing Stack");
           return this.stk.reduce((acc, cv, i, arr, ) = > {
               console.log(cv);
           return (i) ? acc + " " + "\n" + cv : cv;
       },
           ''
       )
           ;
       }

       function MyStack() {
           this.st = 10;
           this.stk = new Array(10);
           this.push = push;
           this.pop = pop;
           this.print = print;
       }

       function doJob() {
           console.log('push pressed!');

           myfunction();
           console.log(s1);
           var x = document.getElementById("tpush").value;
           s1.push(x);

           document.getElementById("tpush").value = "";
       }

       function doJob1() {
           console.log('pop pressed!');
           var y = s1.pop();
           document.getElementById("tpop").value = y;
           document.getElementById("tdisplay").value = s1.print();
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: i have come up with the solution for pop function but still figuring how to go for checkbox

Comment: For the checkbox, wouldn't it be: ```document.getElementById("stack1").checked == true``` the way I implemented it in the ```myFunction()```